# ActionScript 3.0 Drawing API question

Tags: actionscript-3, drawing

How can I create such a shape using the Drawing API?

[image]

where red means filled and white means not filled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In flash the default "winding rule" is even odd.  So, if you draw multiple shapes with the same fill that overlap, they alternate between filled and unfilled.

```
var size:Number = 200;

graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
graphics.lineStyle(1);
graphics.drawRect((stage.stageWidth - size)/2, (stage.stageHeight - size)/2, size, size);
graphics.drawCircle(stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2, size/2 - 10);
graphics.drawCircle(stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2, size/2 - 30);
graphics.endFill();
```